# Validation associated models rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

I have several model associations in one form. I would like to validate the presence of each nested attribute.

I have the Product model, and for example I have this:

Product.rb

```
  has_many :ships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :sizes, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ships
  attr_accessible :ships_attributes
  attr_accessible :size_tokens
  attr_reader :size_tokens
```

So I would like to validate the presence of :ships and :size_tokens when I send the action of my product's form. How can I validate the presence of those attributes?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validates_presence_of` for both. You can find a detailed explanation in [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried it, but I have a problem with my ships_attributes, because it has two more attributes, how can I validate that?

Comment: Any attribute of Ship can be validated in the Ship model itself.